# Login and ask for permission only on web like facebookSessionLoginBehavior.ForcingWebView but for the authorization too

Tags: authorization, behavior, facebook-login, login-control, facebook-authorization

I'm not sure if it's the right place to ask but here is my problem.
I'm doing a game for ipad in unity and I'm using the socialnetwork plugin from prime31.

*The situation:*

When you arrive to the end of level, the game gives you your score and ask if you want to submit it to facebook. If you do, I my script I've done a system that checks if you are logged in, if you aren't it ask you to login and then the system checks if the app has the publish permissions and if not it ask you. If all theses if are true it posts a message to your wall straight. So hopefully the asking part needs to be done only once.

*The problem:*

When the ipad swap between the game and the facebook app to login, the ipad shutdown the game for saving memory. I've tried to reduce the scene, but it's hard to reduce it more than it is. So I thought maybe I should open that facebook login and authorisation inGame. For that I'm using this line:

setSessionLoginBehavior(FacebookSessionLoginBehavior.ForcingWebView);

And it does exactly what I want, doesn't crash all good really. But the problem is that it only works for the login, and when I ask the publish permission it switches to the facebook app to ask the permission and therefore crashes.

So how can I ask the permission in the same way of the FacebookSessionLoginBehavior.ForcingWebView.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Boris